# Java type variance, consumer of generic type

Tags: java, contravariance

I am struggling to understand how variance works in Java.

In the following example, I define a function `test` which takes a `Consumer`. The function is defined without contravariance, so I would expect that `Consumer<Object>` is not a subtype of `Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>>`. Yet, the code compiles, and test accepts the lambda `Variance:::superAction`.

What am I missing?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Variance {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(Variance::exactMatchAction);
    test(Variance::superAction);
  }

  private static void exactMatchAction(Pair<Animal, Animal> pair) {
    System.out.println(pair.getLeft().getClass().getName());
  }

  private static void superAction(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());
  }

  private static void test(Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>> action) {
    action.accept(ImmutablePair.of(new Animal(), new Animal()));
    action.accept(ImmutablePair.of(new Dog(), new Dog()));
  }

  static class Animal {  }

  static class Dog extends Animal {  }
}
```

Edit: Per @Thielo's comment, the reference `superAction` is desugared to a `Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>>` NOT a `Consumer<Object>`.

The correct type to give the `test` method is something like:

```
void test(Consumer<? super Pair<? extends Animal, ? extends Animal>>)
```

This type will allow us to pass a `Consumer<Object>` to `test`, and also allow us to call the consumer with arguments like `Pair<Dog, Dog>` instead of just `Pair<Animal, Animal>`.

As a follow-up question, with this updated type for test, it will not accept a method reference like `void exactMatchAction<Pair<Animal, Animal>>` anymore, only `void exactMatchAction<Pair<? extends Animal, ? extends Animal>>`. Why is this?

Comment: No warnings as far as I can tell.

Comment: Not sure how this is implemented, but it does make sense. A Consumer of Objects can also consume Pairs. You do get an error if you change that parameter to say, a String, right?

Comment: Truly, I don't know. But my guess is this has to do with how `@FunctionalInterface` is handled. It probably doesn't care about the type parameters of the interface itself, only how they're referred to in the method. So the method `Object -> void` can probably used as a `Pair<> -> void`, since if it can consume *any object*, then of course in can consume a pair.

Comment: From my understanding of variance, generic types in Java should be invariant by default. To make `Consumer<Object>` a subtype of `Consumer<Pair<L, R>>`, we would have to modify the declaration of `test` to `void test(Consumer<? super Pair<Animal, Animal>)`.

Comment: You don't get a `Consumer<Object>`. Your lambda is typed according to what you need in that line. So it is still a `Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>>`. If you used the same method reference in a different context, you might get a `Consumer<Number>` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks @Thilo. Replacing the method reference with an anonymous class like `new Consumer<Object> { ... }` reveals the type error. I'm still struggling to wrap my head around it, though. How exactly does the lambda desugar the lambda into a Consumer, and how are the types determined?

Answer (score 1):

Method reference expressions (such as your `Variance::superAction`) are *poly expressions* (JLS8, 15.13).  The type of a poly expression may be influenced by the expression's *target type* (JLS8, 15.3), which is the type expected in that context (JLS8, 5), i.e., `Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>>`, in your case.

The details are spelled out in JLS8, 15.13.2.  The basic idea is that there is special handling for functional interface types such as `Consumer`.  Specifically, the method type only need be *congruent* to the function type (which is `Pair<Animal, Animal> -> void`-- note that `Consumer` has vanished from the type consideration here), which is satisfied by "identif[ying] a single compile-time declaration corresponding to the reference" (and having `void` as return type).  Here, the notion of "identifying" a declaration goes back to 15.12.2 and basically describes the method overload resolution process.  In other words, the language now takes the function parameters expected for `Consumer<Pair<Animal, Animal>>.accept()` (i.e., `Pair<Animal, Animal>`) and checks whether the method reference could be called with that (this resolves overloading in case there are multiple static methods with the same name).